# Why does my output on sqlite inner join multiplies?

Tags: java, sqlite, join

I have 2 tables..

I will represent the data inn array....

`table1` columns are `t1_id, t1_value`

`table2` columns are `t2_id, t2_value, t1_id(FK)`

1. `table1={{1,data1},{2,data2}};`
2. `table2={{1,d1,t1.1},{2,d2,t1.1},{3,d3,t1.2},{4,d4,t1.2}};`

i have a query of..

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT t2_value FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1
             ON table2.t1_id=(SELECT t1_id FROM table1 WHERE t1_value='my_value');")
```

I got the right value i needed but instead of just..

```
d1
d2
```

what I got is..

```
d1
d2
d1
d2
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try this:

`SELECT t2_value FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.t1_id=table1.t1_id WHERE table1.t1_value='my_value`'

Comment: i got an error.. might because of my code.. i'll update you as soon as i figured if your answer is what i need.. and tnx..

Comment: I'm back.. it seems my error is due to typo... and tnx your answer is precise and clear...

Comment: yippee, my first selected answer at stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table2.t2_value FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.t1_id = table1.t1_id 
WHERE table1.t1_value='my_value'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)